# Pivot query error when added to a stored procedure, but runs OK in query builder window

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

When i run this query in as a regular SQL it runs fine and I get the correct results.  Now, i want to make this query a dynamic by having the user add some dates such as the @dtFROM and @dtTO date.  These are user supply dates from my application.  Now, i'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL server to run this, but these is an error about ")" that is mis-placed.  I have looked at this and test portion of the query without any success.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[usp_Cleaner_KG_per_Date]
@dtFrom datetime,
@dtTo datetime

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Packdate VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT  @Packdate = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT
                        '],[' + ((LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, PackDate, 120), 10)))
                        FROM    vw_CleanerSummary2015 where (PackDate >= @dtFROM) and (Packdate <= @dtTO)
                        ORDER BY '],[' + ((LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, PackDate, 120), 10)))
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT     ID,KG,PackDate
FROM         vw_CleanerSummary2015
GROUP BY Packdate,ID,[KG/HR]
)t
PIVOT (sum(KG) FOR Packdate
in ('+@Packdate+')) AS pvt'

EXECUTE (@query)
```

Comment: Have you taken the value in `@query`, after the `SET` statement, and ran that successfully?

Comment: Yes.  It runs successful.

Comment: Here's the error from SQL Manager: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_Cleaner_KG_per_Date, Line 28
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is all of your procedure code the issue is likely that you are missing the closing `END` after the `execute` to match the opening `BEGIN`.

Comment: Thank you.  That solved the problem.  Amateur mistake.